# How to return a value from Infinite Loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, infinite-loop

I have a doubt  which may be very trivial for many out there.
I am unable to understand how to return a value from infinite running Loop?(if possible)

I have gone through various sources in the internet where they have all advised to go with **MultiThreading**.

But sadly I am unable to grasp the idea how can Threading be helpful in this case.
Here is my simulated feature I wish to implement :-

```
void processReturnedValue(){
    for(;;){
        String currentTime = retrieveCurrentTime(); 
        doSomethingWithReturenedValue(currentTime);
        delay(15000); // function to incur delay for 15 Seconds
   }
}

String retrieveCurrentTime(){
     for(;;){
         return currentDateTime.getDayOfYear()+ "_" + currentDateTime.getHour() + "_" +    currentDateTime.getMinute() + "_" + currentDateTime.getSecond();
     delay(15000); // function to incur delay for 15 Seconds
   }
}
```

**I shall be highly obliged if someone can throw some light regarding my doubt.
If possible kindly provide a small working simulated example with respect to mine.
Thanking you in anticipation.**

Comment: Why do you need the loop inside `retrieveCurrentTime`? Can't you just return the current time whenever it's called?

Comment: Nope.I simulated my requirement where I need to process some data in an interval of every 15 seconds and return the same to the caller function.

Comment: The for-statement in the  `retrieveCurrentTIme` method does not loop. It will go only once and will finish reaching the return statement. The `deelay(15000)` is unreacheable in this piece of code.

Comment: Yap,thats what I want @Kamil ,I dont want it to return although return is used

Comment: @ArchiacCoder `processReturnedValue` is already calling `retrieveCurrentTime` every 15 seconds. You don't need to delay another 15 seconds inside `retrieveCurrentTime`.

Comment: @ArchiacCoder the code in the `retrieveCurrentTime` method will not even compile. You will need to drop the line with `delay(15000)` and you can remove the `for (;;) {}` statement as it does nothing in this case.

Comment: @mastran Actually I am getting data on a socket in retriveCurrentTime so,I shall connect to client on while true loop  waiting for client (with defined timeout) and then return it to caller

Comment: Do your requirements allow you to migrate away from the infinite loop approach to adopt a `Scheduler` approach?That will alleviate becoming trapped in an infinite loop, immediate increase your implementation flexibility, and achieve the same periodic data retrieval in a much simpler way.

Comment: If your goal is to eventually do something, an exception handler (try-catch block) would eventually trigger if enough memory were consumed - and you could add logic to cause a small amount of memory to be consumed without garbage collection each iteration

Comment: @ArchiacCoder We really need more clarification on what your goal is. `I need to process some data in an interval of every 15 seconds and return the same to the caller function... I am getting data on a socket in 'retriveCurrentTime' so, I shall connect to client on 'while true' loop waiting for client (with defined timeout) and then return it to caller` still isn't very clear.

Comment: @Sean Yes I can go with Scheduler Approach ,But inside Scheduler I have to have a while True as I get data on socket every n seconds.So,ultimately,I guess it boils down to same

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.My requirement :-                                                                                                                      i.get json data from a SOCKET from 2 client every n seconds.(2 Threads)                                                     ii.return back the value from each function inside thread to main Method.                                iii.main method calls business logic based on the rules and data received from both clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning, assign the value to a shared variable:

```
private final AtomicReference<String> currentTime = new AtomicReference<>();

// Thread 1:
void processReturnedValue() {
    for(;;) {
        doSomethingWithReturenedValue(currentTime.get());
        delay(15000); // function to incur delay for 15 Seconds
   }
}

// Thread 2:
String retrieveCurrentTime() {
    for(;;) {
        currentTime.set(currentDateTime.getDayOfYear()+ "_" + currentDateTime.getHour() + "_" +    currentDateTime.getMinute() + "_" + currentDateTime.getSecond());
        delay(15000); // function to incur delay for 15 Seconds
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.I feel I need to go with this approach.